# Why database doesn't call onCreate in service?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm quite new in xamarin and have a task to create some kind of personal organiser on Android. Main feature is creating notes, todos, events in different activities and then save, delete, edit in various screens too. For this reason, I use SQLiteOpenHelper to create database in service to have an access from each activity and then call methods from it. My service is hybrid so i bind in each activity while it works. Unfortunately, SQLiteOpenHelper.OnCreate doesn't call. I logged most of possible mistaken parts and it showed a miss in creating DB. Here is my code.

**Services.cs**

```
using Android.Util;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;
using Android.App;
using FinallyApp;
using Android.Database;
using OrgDatabase1;
using Android.Database.Sqlite;
using System;

namespace DatabaseService
{

    [Service(Name = "com.xamarin.DBservice")]
    public class DBConnectService : Service
    {
        DatabaseHelper DbHelper;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        public IBinder Binder { get; private set; }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {

            Log.Debug("DemoService", "DemoService started");

            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            // This method is optional to implement

            base.OnCreate();
            DbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            Log.Debug("INSERVICE", "OncreateService");


            db = DbHelper.ReadableDatabase;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            // This method must always be implemented
            Log.Debug("Service.OnBind", "OnBinded");
            this.Binder = new DBConnectBinder(this);
            return this.Binder;
        }

        public override bool OnUnbind(Intent intent)
        {
            // This method is optional to implement

            return base.OnUnbind(intent);
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            // This method is optional to implement

            Binder = null;
            base.OnDestroy();
        }


        public ICursor GetTable(string table_name)
        {
            switch (table_name)
            {
                case DatabaseHelper.NOTE_TABLE:
                    string[] projection = { DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CREATION_DATE };
                    var cursor = db.Query(DatabaseHelper.NOTE_TABLE, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
                    return cursor;
                case DatabaseHelper.EVENT_TABLE:

                    return null;
                case DatabaseHelper.TODO_TABLE:

                    return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public ContentValues GetItem(string table_name, int position)
        {
            switch (table_name)
            {
                case DatabaseHelper.NOTE_TABLE:
                    string[] projection = { DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CREATION_DATE };
                    var cursor = db.Query(DatabaseHelper.NOTE_TABLE, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
                    cursor.MoveToPosition(position);
                    using (ContentValues item = new ContentValues())
                    {
                        item.Put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME)));
                        item.Put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
                        item.Put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CREATION_DATE, cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CREATION_DATE)));
                        item.Put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID, cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
                        return item;
                    }
                case DatabaseHelper.EVENT_TABLE:

                    return null;
                case DatabaseHelper.TODO_TABLE:

                    return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public void InsertNote(string name, string description)
        {
            using (ContentValues contentV = new ContentValues())
            {
                contentV.Put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, name);
                contentV.Put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);
                contentV.Put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CREATION_DATE, DateTime.Now.ToString("g"));
                db.Insert(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, null, contentV);
            }

        }
        public void DeleteItem(string table_name, int id)
        {
            db.Delete(table_name, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id.ToString(), null);
        }
        public void UpdateItem(string table_name, int id, ContentValues values)
        {
            db.Update(table_name, values, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id.ToString(), null);
        }
    }

    public class DBConnectBinder : Binder
    {
        public DBConnectBinder(DBConnectService service)
        {
            this.Service = service;
        }

        public DBConnectService Service { get; private set; }

        public ICursor GetTable(string table_name)
        {
            return Service.GetTable(table_name);
        }
        public ContentValues GetItem(string table_name, int position)
        {
            return Service.GetItem(table_name, position);
        }
        public void InsertNote(string name, string description)
        {
            Service.InsertNote(name, description);
        }
        public void DeleteItem(string table_name, int id)
        {
            Service.DeleteItem(table_name, id);
        }
        public void UpdateItem(string table_name, int id, ContentValues values)
        {
            Service.UpdateItem(table_name, id, values);
        }
    }

    public class DBConnectionServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
    {
        public DBConnectionServiceConnection(Activity activity)
        {
            IsConnected = false;
            Binder = null;
            this.activity = activity;
        }
        private Activity activity;
        public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }
        public DBConnectBinder Binder { get; private set; }

        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            Binder = service as DBConnectBinder;
            IsConnected = this.Binder != null;
            Log.Debug("OnConnected", "Connected");
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                Log.Debug("IsConnected", "true");
                if (activity as MainActivity != null)
                {
                    MainActivity act = (MainActivity)activity;
                    act.GetDataFromService();
                }
                else if (activity as MainActivity != null)
                {
                    NoteItemPageActivity act = (NoteItemPageActivity)activity;
                    act.GetItemFromService();
                }
                else if (activity as CreationActivity != null)
                {
                    CreationActivity act = (CreationActivity)activity;
                    act.PrepareForCreate();
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            IsConnected = false;
            Binder = null;

        }


    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using OrgDatabase1; 
using Android.Database;
using Android.Database.Sqlite;
using Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using DatabaseService;
using Android.Util;

namespace FinallyApp
{
    [Activity(MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {
        TextView textMessage;
        BottomNavigationView navigation;

        ICursor cursor;
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        NoteAlbumAdapter mAdapter;
        Toolbar toolbar;

        DBConnectionServiceConnection Dbconnection;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            textMessage = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message);
            navigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigation);
            navigation.SetOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(DBConnectService)));


            toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.SetTitle(Resource.String.title_note);
        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            if (Dbconnection == null)
            {
                this.Dbconnection = new DBConnectionServiceConnection(this);
            }
            Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(this, typeof(DBConnectService));
            BindService(serviceToStart, this.Dbconnection, Bind.AutoCreate);

        }
        public void GetDataFromService()
        {
            Log.Debug("status", "InActivity");
            if (cursor == null)
            {
                Log.Debug("status", "ifCursorNull");
                cursor = Dbconnection.Binder.GetTable(DatabaseHelper.NOTE_TABLE);
                mAdapter = new NoteAlbumAdapter(cursor);
                mAdapter.ItemClick += OnNoteItemClick;
                mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
            else mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

        }
        void OnNoteItemClick(object sender, int position)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NoteItemPageActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("position", position);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
        public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.navigation_note:
                    textMessage.SetText(Resource.String.title_note);
                    toolbar.SetTitle(Resource.String.title_note);
                    toolbar.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.NoteMainColor);
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.navigation_todo:
                    textMessage.SetText(Resource.String.title_todo);
                    toolbar.SetTitle(Resource.String.title_todo);
                    toolbar.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.TodoMainColor);
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.navigation_event:
                    textMessage.SetText(Resource.String.title_event);
                    toolbar.SetTitle(Resource.String.title_event);
                    toolbar.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.EventMainColor);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
        protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.top_menus, menu);
            var delete_item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.menu_delete);
            delete_item.SetVisible(false);
            var edit_item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.menu_edit);
            edit_item.SetVisible(false);
            var save_item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.menu_save);
            save_item.SetVisible(false);
            var cancel_item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.menu_cancel);
            cancel_item.SetVisible(false);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.menu_create:
                    var current_section = navigation.SelectedItemId;
                    switch (current_section)
                    {
                        case Resource.Id.navigation_note:
                            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CreationActivity));
                            intent.PutExtra("CreationType", "Note");
                            StartActivity(intent);
                            return true;
                        case Resource.Id.navigation_todo:
                            var intent2 = new Intent(this, typeof(CreationActivity));
                            intent2.PutExtra("CreationType", "Todo");
                            StartActivity(intent2);
                            return true;
                        case Resource.Id.navigation_event:
                            var intent3 = new Intent(this, typeof(CreationActivity));
                            intent3.PutExtra("CreationType", "Event");
                            StartActivity(intent3);
                            return true;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            UnbindService(Dbconnection);
            base.OnStop();
        }
        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            StopService(new Intent(this, typeof(DBConnectService)));
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

**SQLite.cs**

```
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using Android.Database.Sqlite;
using Android.Database;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;

namespace OrgDatabase1
{
    public class DatabaseHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public const string NOTE_TABLE = "Notes";
        public const string EVENT_TABLE = "Events";
        public const string TODO_TABLE = "Todos";
        public const string COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        public const string COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        public const string COLUMN_CREATION_DATE = "creation_date";
        public const string COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
        public const string COLUMN_DEADLINE = "deadline";
        public static readonly string DbName = "database.db";
        public static readonly int DatabaseVersion = 1;
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) : base(context, DbName, null, DatabaseVersion) { }
        public override void OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.ExecSQL("CREATE TABLE [" + NOTE_TABLE + "] ([" + COLUMN_ID + "] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [" + COLUMN_NAME + "] TEXT NOT NULL, [" + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + "] TEXT, [" + COLUMN_CREATION_DATE + "] TEXT NOT NULL);");
            Log.Debug("DATABASE","Access");

        }
        public override void OnUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You expect `SQLiteOpenHelper.OnCreate` to be called, but `DatabaseHelper.OnCreate` doesn't call `base.OnCreate(db)`. I don't know a thing about xamarin or your service architecture, so I can't help with anything specific

Comment: It's not necessary to call `base.OnCreate`. App worked well when i was using Activity as a Context.I suppose fault is in another place.

Comment: I suppose your question would be more clear, if you complain about `DatabaseHelper.OnCreate` not being called. If you set `DatabaseVersion = 2`, is the `OnUpgrade` method called then? If so, what's the `oldVersion` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLiteOpenHelper.OnCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) will only run when the database is created for the first time. That is to say, if the app has already been deployed and run on your device, this method won't run again.

You can uninstall your app first and re-deploy it to your device and this time it should run.

To uninstall your app, you can use adb:

```
adb uninstall your.package.name
```

Referring [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run).

Comment: You're right but `OnCreate` doesn't call at first time. That's the point. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your scenario, I used your code above and commentted out everything missed, OnCreate works good. If it's not working on your side, maybe you can try adding on things step by step and see what's affecting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, but I feel a little bit dumb because I have coded incorrect.

in `db.Insert(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, null, contentV);` I call column name instead of table name. That's all.